# How to pass additional parameters to curve_fit in Julia?

Tags: julia, curve-fitting

I have a dataset that I would like to fit to my function `pbase(x,pars)` with Julia's `curve_fit`, whereby `pars` is supposed to contain a non-fitting parameter that controls which functional model is chosen. The function looks like this:

```
function pbase(d,pars)
    typ=pars[1]
    pimb=fill(-5.81,length(d))
    @. x=(length(pars) == 3) ? pars[2]*(log10(d)-log10(pars[3])) : pars[2]*log10(d)
    if typ == "tanh"
        @. pimb*=tanh(x)
    elseif typ == "arctan"
        @. pimb*=atan(x)
    end
    pimb
end
```

i.e., `par[1]` contains the selector that is not to be changed during fitting and `par[2:3]` contain the actual fitting parameters. Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up discussing the problem on discourse.julia.org and got a solution to it from Steven Johnson in [this thread](https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-pass-additional-parameters-to-curve-fit-in-julia/103031).

Comment: Please copy the essential part of the answer from the link here

Comment: The essential part of Steven's reply is this code snippet:
`p1 = fixed_parameter;
curve_fit((x, p) -> pbase(x, [p1; p]), xdata, ydata, p0)`
I use LsqFit.jl for fitting.